# SSIS Issue -- Related to #Temp Table Referencing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, ssis, ssis-2014

I am completely new to SSIS.I am using SQL Server 2014.

I am not able to understand what is wrong with code as it results good in SSMS.

I use OLEDB connection as source assistant and input the below code in SQL Command option.

I am using the below query as part of exporting source T-SQL output to Flat file.

I am getting below issue while creating a SSIS package. can anyone help me on this.

Below is the code I use (I modified for finding complete backup Info purpose) :

```
if object_id ('tempdb..#temp1') is not null
drop table tempdb..#temp1

create table #temp1 
([server] nvarchar(200),
[name] nvarchar(200),
[last full backup] datetime ,
[last differential backup] datetime,
[last log backup] datetime )

insert into  #temp1

SELECT  (select @@SERVERNAME) as Server,name ,


            d AS 'Last Full Backup' ,
            i AS 'Last Differential Backup' ,
            l AS 'Last log Backup'
    FROM    ( SELECT    db.name ,
                        db.state_desc ,
                        db.recovery_model_desc ,                                            
                        type ,
                        backup_finish_date

                        FROM      master.sys.databases db

                        LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset a ON a.database_name = db.name 

            ) AS Sourcetable 
        PIVOT 
            ( MAX(backup_finish_date) FOR type IN ( D, I, L ) ) AS MostRecentBackup 

if object_id ('tempdb..#temp2') is not null
drop table tempdb..#temp2


create table #temp2
([server] nvarchar(200),
[name] nvarchar(200),
Backupsize nvarchar(max))

insert into  #temp2

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--Most Recent Full Database Backup for Each Database - Detailed 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
SELECT  
   A.[Server] As SQLServerName, 
  A.database_name As DatabaseName, 
   --A.last_db_backup_date As DatabaseLastBackupDate,  
--   B.backup_start_date As DatabaseBackupStartDate,  
   CAST(B.backup_size/1024.0/1024/1024 as decimal(10,2))
   --B.backupset_name 

FROM 
   ( 
   SELECT   
       CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
       msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  
       MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) AS last_db_backup_date 
   FROM    msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
       INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id  
   WHERE   msdb..backupset.type = 'D' and server_name = (select @@servername) AND name = 'CommVault Galaxy Backup'
   GROUP BY 
       msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name  
   ) AS A 

   LEFT JOIN  

   ( 
   SELECT   
   CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.expiration_date, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_size,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.name AS backupset_name, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.description 
FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
   INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id  
WHERE  msdb..backupset.type = 'D' 
   ) AS B 
   ON A.[server] = B.[server] AND A.[database_name] = B.[database_name] AND A.[last_db_backup_date] = B.[backup_finish_date] 
ORDER BY  
   A.database_name 



   if object_id ('tempdb..#tempdiff') is not null
drop table tempdb..#tempdiff

create table #tempdiff
([server] nvarchar(200),
[name] nvarchar(200),
DiffBkpGB nvarchar(MAX),
backupset_name nvarchar(max))

insert into  #tempdiff

SELECT  
   A.[Server] As SQLServerName, 
   A.database_name As DatabaseName, 
   --A.last_db_backup_date As DatabaseLastBackupDate,  
   --B.backup_start_date As DatabaseBackupStartDate,  
   --B.backup_size/1024/1024 as DifferentialBackupSizeGB,  
   CAST(B.backup_size/1024.0/1024/1024 as decimal(10,3)) as DiffBkpGB ,
   B.backupset_name 

FROM 
   ( 
   SELECT   
       CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
       msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  
       MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) AS last_db_backup_date 
   FROM    msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
       INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id  
   WHERE   msdb..backupset.type = 'I' and server_name = (select @@servername) AND name = 'CommVault Galaxy Backup'
   GROUP BY 
       msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name  
   ) AS A 

   LEFT JOIN  

   ( 
   SELECT   
   CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.expiration_date, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_size,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.name AS backupset_name, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.description 
FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
   INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id  
WHERE  msdb..backupset.type = 'I' 
   ) AS B 
   ON A.[server] = B.[server] AND A.[database_name] = B.[database_name] AND A.[last_db_backup_date] = B.[backup_finish_date] 
ORDER BY  
   A.database_name  

   if object_id ('tempdb..#templog') is not null
drop table tempdb..#templog

create table #templog
([server] nvarchar(200),
[name] nvarchar(200),
LogBkpGB nvarchar(MAX)
)

insert into  #templog

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--Most Recent Log Database Backup for Each Database - Detailed 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
SELECT  
   A.[Server] As SQLServerName, 
  A.database_name As DatabaseName, 
   --A.last_db_backup_date As DatabaseLastBackupDate,  
   --B.backup_start_date As DatabaseBackupStartDate,  
   --B.backup_size/1024/1024 as LogBackupSizeGB, 
   CAST(B.backup_size/1024.0/1024/1024 as decimal(10,3)) AS LogBkpGB  
   --B.backupset_name 

FROM 
   ( 
   SELECT   
       CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
       msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  
       MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) AS last_db_backup_date 
   FROM    msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
       INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id  
   WHERE   msdb..backupset.type = 'L' and server_name = (select @@servername) AND name = 'CommVault Galaxy Backup'
   GROUP BY 
       msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name  
   ) AS A 

   LEFT JOIN  

   ( 
   SELECT   
   CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.expiration_date, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_size,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.name AS backupset_name, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.description 
FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
   INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id  
WHERE  msdb..backupset.type = 'L' 
   ) AS B 
   ON A.[server] = B.[server] AND A.[database_name] = B.[database_name] AND A.[last_db_backup_date] = B.[backup_finish_date] 
ORDER BY  
   A.database_name 

   select (select getdate()) as CurrentDateTime,#temp1.server, #temp1.name as Database_Name, #temp1.[last full backup] as Last_Full_Backup, #temp2.Backupsize as FullBkpGB, #temp1.[last differential backup] as Last_Differential_Backup,#tempdiff.DiffBkpGB, #temp1.[last log backup] as Last_Log_Backup,
   #templog.LogBkpGB, #tempdiff.backupset_name

   from #temp1 left join #temp2 on #temp1.server = #temp2.server and #temp1.name = #temp2.name
   left join #tempdiff on #temp1.server = #tempdiff.server and #temp1.name = #tempdiff.name
   left join #templog on #temp1.server = #templog.server and #temp1.name = #templog.name
```

When I am working on creating a new SSIS package I get the following issue. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Can multiple people run this SSIS package concurrently? If not, then just use a permanent table (and simply truncate it after each run). If so, use a permanent table with a session id key (and delete your session's rows after every run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace temp tables, if you can, with table variables.  The metadata analysis is used against the last SELECT statement in the batch.